# How to grep a particular string from a log for particular period of time

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I want to find a string from log for particular interval of time

```
grep -i <string> logfile name
```

This is used to find particular string only

Comment: This depends on time format that is used in the log file.

Comment: Please edit your question, showing what the date format in your logfile looks like.

Comment: What is in the log file. Please post an example of the lines.